# How to extract the class name out of List< Func< Int32 > >

Tags: c#, .net

How do I get the name out of the list?

e.g

```
static void Main()
{
    var methods = new List<Func<int>>();
    methods.Add(() => new ThisCss().useThis(0));

    // Output ThisCss here from methods
    // i.e Console.WriteLine(methods[0].ClassName).. or something like that

}

class ThisCss
{
    public int useThis(int num)
    {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

So just to clarify I want to get the name of the class out of the 0 index of the list of functions. So in this case it would be 'ThisCss'.

Comment: could you intent your `return 0;`? it  would add a little clarity for the others

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to break down a function call into an expression tree.

You cannot do this to a plain old `Func`, but you can do this to a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

public class ThisCss
{
    public int useThis(int num)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static Type ExtractClassType(Expression<Func<int>> methodCall)
    {
        if (methodCall.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
        {
            MethodCallExpression memberExpression = (System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)methodCall.Body;
            MethodInfo memberInfo = memberExpression.Method;
            return memberInfo.DeclaringType;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to extract a method call from this expression");
        }
    }



    public static void Main()
    {
        var methods = new List<Expression<Func<int>>>();
        methods.Add(() => new ThisCss().useThis(0));

        var type = ExtractClassType(methods[0]);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", type);
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that return the inherited class if the class had one?

Comment: @bobtoss If this is virtual method override, then it would return the base class where the method is defined. If you wanted to get the type of the actual instance, you may have to traverse the expression tree to get more information.

Comment: How would I go about invoking it like a normal Func?

Comment: @bobtoss: You can convert an `Expression` to an invokable `Func` by calling the method `Expression.Compile`. Note that, for this to work, the class `ThisCss` must be declared as `public`.

Answer (score 0):

`Func<...>` is a `delegate` and all `delegate` instances derive from `System.Delegate` which has the `Method` property that returns a `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` which contains meta information about the actual CLR method being called including its containing type/class (there are no free-functions in the CLR, all functions are methods).

Try this:

```
foreach( Func<Int32> f in methods ) {
    MethodInfo mi = f.Method;
    String typeName = mi.DeclaringType.FullName;
    Console.WriteLine( typeName + "." + mi.Name );
}
```

Note that if you reference an anonymous function or Lambda-function then the *real* `DeclaringType` will be a C#-compiler generated type with an unpredictable or unexpected name (which you can see using a CIL disassembly tool like `Ildasm`, ILSpy, or RedGate Reflector.

Comment: Returns: 'Program.Program+<>c.<Main>b__0_0'.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'Tuple' if you can change the return type?

```
var methods = new List<Tuple<string, Func<int>>>();

methods.Add(new Tuple<string, Func<int>>(nameof(ThisCss), () => new ThisCss().useThis(0)));
methods.Add(new Tuple<string, Func<int>>(nameof(ThisCss2), () => new ThisCss2().useThis(0)));

var className = methods[0].Item1;
```

In C# 7.0

```
var methods = new List<(string ClassName, Func<int> Func)>();

methods.Add((nameof(ThisCss), () => new ThisCss().useThis(0)));
methods.Add((nameof(ThisCss2), () => new ThisCss2().useThis(0)));

var className = methods[0].ClassName;
```

Comment: haha, not sure why I didn't think of using a tuple. Thank you.